# Tangent line and parabola

Tags: calculus

Seems like this question should be straight forward, so I'm guessing it is the interpretation of the question that is messing me up.

---

***Find the coordinates of all points on the graph of $y=1-x^2$ at which the tangent line passes thru $(2,0).$***

---

My approach:

The tangent line to $f(x)$ has a slope of $-2x$.  If it passes thru $(2,0)$ then I can write the equation of the tangent line as $y=-4x+8.$ So, I just need to find the intersections of this line and the parabola function given.

Setting the 2 y values equal to find the intersections, I get,

$-4x+8=-x^2+1$ or $x^2-4x+7=0$.  This quadratic has imaginary roots, so something is not right in my logic or approach or method of solution.  I've checked the arithmetic.  Can you assist?

Comment: The equation you wrote is not of the tangent line.

Comment: $(2,0)$ does not lie on the parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the tangent touches the parabola  at the point $P(x_0,1-x_0^2)$

The slope at the point $P$ $$m=-2x_0$$

The equation of the line passing through $(2,0)$ and with slope $m$ is

$$y=-2x_0(x-2)$$

But this line also passes through the point $P$

Thus $$1-x_0^2=-2x_0(x_0-2)$$

$$x_0=2\pm \sqrt 3$$
$$y_0=1-x_0^2=-6\mp 4\sqrt 3$$

Points are $P_1(2+\sqrt3,-6-4\sqrt 3)$  and $P_2(2-\sqrt 3,-6+4\sqrt 3)$

Comment: totally clear now.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Tangent line equation at $(a,1-a^2)$ is

$$y=-2a(x-a)+(1-a^2)$$

it goes through $(2,0)$ if

$$0=-2a(2-a)+(1-a^2)$$

or

$$a^2-4a+1=0$$
$$\Delta=12$$
thus

$$a=2\pm \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: How is $\Delta'$ defined?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $\Delta'=(\frac b2)^2-ac$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Your $x$ is doing double duty.  It can't travel about the line and parabola and also be part of the slope formula at a certain point.

Instead, suppose the intersection happens at $x=a$.  Then the equation of the line is $y=-2ax+4a$.  At the intersection point you have

$$1-a^2 = -2a^2+4a$$

So $a=2\pm \sqrt{3}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $P (t,1-t^2)$ be a point on the parabola .

Tangent line has slope $-2t$ at $P(t,1-t^2)$. It passes through $(2,0)$.

Slope of line joining $P$ and $(2,0)$ equals $-2t$.

$\dfrac{1-t^2}{t-2} = -2t.$

$t^2-4t+1=0.$

Solve for $t$.